# Is attack speed or AD better against structures

Tags: league-of-legends

What is more gold efficient to destroy a turret faster: buying ad or attack speed?

To be more precise, if I was to to attack the tower with 1 item either, "[Dagger](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dagger)" or "[Long-Sword](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Long_Sword)", which would destroy it faster? Also, which destroys a turret faster, AD or AS Runes?

Comment: I dont know the exact values, but it would be a simple math equation. )(damage dealt per auto attack) * (attacks per second) = (damage per second). in my opinion, i think attack speed is more important/does more, but i dont feel like doing math on it

Comment: Ideally you would want to get a mix of both, as attack speed essentially works as a multiplier.

Comment: Note that different champios have different base AS, which means flat ad helps them more than others. Those champions also get more Attack Speed from a Dagger than others. Not to mention that it depends heavily if you can use auto resets (Like Garen, or Shyvana) and if you have items to help you do said resets (Hydra). Furthermore, the Sheen line of items also brings a lot to the table. I'm not really sure if this should be closed for being too broad due to how many variables there are (Since different champs have diff ASs), but for now i'm restraining on voting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turrets start with 40 armor which equals about 28.6% damage reduction.

Caitlyn at level 1 has 53.7 AD and .568 attack speed.

53.7 * .714 = **38.3** damage per auto attack. 38.3 * .568 = **21.8 DPS** to a tower.

Add in a long sword you get:

(53.7 + 10) * .714 = **45.5** damage per auto attack. 45.5 * .568 = **25.8 DPS** an 18.3% increase costing 350 gold (1% per 19 gold)

Adding in a dagger instead:

53.7 * .714 = **38.3** damage per auto attack. 38.3 * (.568 * 1.12) = **24.4 DPS** a 12% increase costing 300 gold (1% per 25 gold)

Long sword is clearly the better option if you are limiting yourself to 1 item even though it is a bit more expensive.

Comment: a dagger costs 300 gold not 400. You might wanna fix that.

Comment: @Jutschge I'm not sure how I mixed that up, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR the longsword is the better option

For this example I'll pick a champion that does not exist but has a **base attack damage of 55** and a **base attack speed of 0.651**. (These values are pretty much the average)

The turret we're focussing is one of the outer turrets. He has 3500 health and 45 armor (it has +5 armor after 6 minutes). This gives him an **effective health value of 5075**. (`3500 * 1.45 = 5075`)

Now for this calculations we will have minions to tank the turret (otherwise it'd gain more armor) but they will deal no damage to it. Since our champion has to kill the turret alone it would take him **93 attacks** (`5075 / 55 = 92.27...`) to kill the turret. With his base attack speed he will attack once every **1.536 seconds** (`1 / 0.651 = 1.5361`) meaning it will take him a total of around **143 seconds** (`93 * 1.5361 =  142.857)` to kill the turret all by himself.

### Dagger

Now  the champion goes back buys a dagger and attacks again. The dagger increased his attack speed to **0.729 attacks per second** (`0.651 * 1.12 = 0.72912`) which means he's attacking once every **1.372 seconds** and thus will speed up the time it takes to kill the turret to roughly **128 seconds** (`1 / 0.729 = 1.3715`, `1.3715 * 93 = 127.6`)

With a dagger you're **10% faster** than without items.

### Longsword

A longsword will simply increase the base AD of the auto attacks meaning that instead of  93 attacks it now takes **79 attacks** (`5075 / 65 = 78.07`) to kill the turret. With the base attack speed of an attack every 1.536 seconds it'll take the total time needed even further down to **121 seconds** (`1.536 * 79 = 121.334`).

With the longsword you'll be **15% faster** compared to having no items at all.

Note that if our imaginary champion had abilities that act as an auto attack reset, flat AD would be even better.